# Max min spanning tree diameter

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

> For $d \geq 1$ determine: $$ \max_{\text{diam}(G) = d} \min
>  \{\text{diam}(T): \, T \, \text{spanning tree of} \, G \} $$

I'm having trouble understanding what this quantity represents. Does this suppose to mean that for every $d$ we find the minimum diameter of $G$'s spanning trees and then the maximum diameter of all those minima?

Can someone explain this in simple words and provide me with a hint on how to find it?

Comment: That's what it says, though I think the original formulation was clearer. Someone else asked the same question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3696676/minimum-diameter-spanning-tree No answer there but maybe the comments are helpful.

Comment: Say $d=2$. Every graph of diameter $2$ has a spanning tree, but we are only interested in spanning trees of minimum diameter for each given graph. (1) The graph $P_3$ has a spanning tree of diameter $2$ (itself). (2) The graph $C_4$ has a spanning tree of diameter $3$, namely $P_4$. (3) The graph $C_5$ has a spanning tree of diameter $4$, namely $P_5$. Is that as bad as it gets? Is there a graph of diameter $2$ whose minimum diameter spanning tree has diameter $5$? Or does every graph of diameter $2$ have a spanning tree of diameter $\le4$? In the latter case, the answer (for $d=2$) is $4$.

Comment: Hint: Every graph of diameter $d$ has a spanning tree of diameter $\le2d$ and that's the best possible: for each $d$ there is a graph of diameter $d$ which has no spanning tree of diameter $\lt2d$.

Comment: @bof So the maximum possible diameter of a spanning tree of a graph of diameter $=d$ is $2d$, right? The part that confuses me is the nested $\min$. Is the final answer $2d$?

Comment: Not "the maximum possible diameter of a spanning tree" but "the maximum possible diameter of a **minimum** diameter spanning tree. The graph $K_{100}$, among its many spanning trees, has spanning trees of diameter $99$ (paths) and spanning trees of diameter $2$ (stars), it's the latter that we're interested in. For each graph, find a ***minimum*** diameter spanning path; what's the worst that it gets for graphs of diameter $d$? Yes, the answer is $2d$.